# How to run the main method on a project where spring boot dependencies are added?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven

I am working on a project but it is not on Eclipse, it is on the web, the only thing I have available to run it is the "run" button that the website gives me. Right now I have the Main class with the main method. If I click on "run" I can see the output from my println statements inside the main method.

However in this project I need to call a web service, for which I'm planning on using RestTemplate, hence I need to add a dependency to the pom file:

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>...</artifactId>
  </dependency>
```

However, once I add that dependency...and I click on the "Run" button, all that is printed on the console is "Hello Maven.", which is not at all what I have in the println statements in the main method.

So it seems that once I add the spring boot dependencies...and I click Run, it no longer reads from the main method from the main class.

What can I do so that once I click on Run, it once again, shows the output from the main method?

Again, this is not Eclipse, it is a website which has its own environment.

Comment: What is the website ?

Comment: @JeanPicard Filtered.ai